# Unconnected lookup in informatica

Tags: lookup, informatica

I am doing an unconnected lookup in my mapping. The workflow is getting succeeded but nothing is getting read.

In session log:

lkp_D_CUST: index cache size = [2646000],Data cache size =[5292032]

Finished transformation for source qualifier [lkp_D_CUST{{DSQ}}]. Total errors [0]

SORT_404223 End of output from sorter transformation srt_VST. Processed 79 rows.

I had joiners in my mapping after this, but nothing is getting executed.
The look up has only a source filter. Inputting a big int value. Condition is also I have checked multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Pls debug using below steps -

1. Compare source and the lookup table data - get a sample data( columns used in lkp condition) form source and check if they are available in lookup file/table adding the filter. Sometime some data can have trailing blank spaces, time in the datetime column in the data. so be careful while using them in condition. Be careful if you are doing any transformation on the joining column. Sometime joins can be case sensitive as well.
2. Check how you are calling unconnected lkp- what are values passed to lkp. if they are correct and having intended values. Check data type,length of return column is matching to the return column of unconnected lkp.

One all checks are fine, keep 2 rows in source and matching rows in unconnected lkp and you can run the session in `verbose data mode` which will log all values in details. Go through this verbose log to see what data value is passed to the unconnected lkp and why its not finding a match.
You can also run mapping in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Please enable `Collect performance data` session property, run the session and expand performance stats in `Workflow Monitor`. Share a screen in case you'd have issues understanding the output. For details please folow steps discussed in [this article](https://etltechsolutions.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/collect-performance-data-in-informatica/).